# How to return instance or sth else using constructor in javascript?

Tags: javascript, constructor

my class definition:

```
var Scregal = function(gallery, opts) {
    //some code
};
```

`var scregal = new Scregal('.gallery-box', options);`

How to return sth different than instance of Scregal inside constructor? is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want to? Wouldn't that be a tad confusing? Sounds like you're looking for a factory pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to return a value other than the implicit `this` from a constructor function. However, you can only return objects, not primitive values. A primitive return value will be ignored and the original `this` will be returned instead.

```
function A() {
  return 'test'; //primitive
}

new A() !== 'test';
new A() instanceof A; //return value ignored

function B() {
  return new String('test'); //wrapper type
}

new B() instanceof String;
new B() == 'test'; //strict equality (===) wouldn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return any object from a constructor and that object is what will be treated as the created value. (If you return a primitive, it will be ignored and the actual created object will be returned).

```js
function Thing(type) {
    if (type === "date") {
        return new Date();
    } else if (type === "string") {
        return new String("Hello!");
    }
}

console.log(new Thing("date"));
console.log(new Thing("string"));
console.log(new Thing());
```

Whether this is a good idea or not is another question.